# The search feature in the drop-down lists does not work (add option 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to activate the search feature in the dynamically generated drop-down lists by using select 2 plugin, but unfortunately the plugin does not work at all.

Any solution would be appreciated.

This is the source code for all the page this plugin is on which I can't get it to work

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table style="text-align: center" id="dynamicAddRemove">
    <tr style="background-color: #007398; color: white; text-align: center">
      <th class="wd-15p fontColor">الحساب</th>
      <th class="wd-15p fontColor">مدين</th>
      <th class="wd-15p fontColor">دائن</th>
      <th class="wd-15p fontColor">وصف</th>
      <th class="wd-10p fontColor"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td">
        <select
          class="form-control select_acount js-example-basic-single"
          name="account[]"
          required
        >
          <option value="1">--1--</option>
          <option value="2">--2--</option>
          <option value="3">--3--</option>
          <option value="4">--4--</option>
          <option value="5">--5--</option>
          <option value="6">--6--</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="td">
        <input
          type="number"
          name="debtor[]"
          id="fname"
          class="form-control debtor arabicNumbers"
          onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69"
          required
        />
      </td>
      <td class="td">
        <input
          type="number"
          name="creditor[]"
          id="james"
          class="form-control creditor arabicNumbers"
          onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69"
          required
        />
      </td>
      <td class="td">
        <input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="mount[]" class="form-control mount" required />
      </td>
      <td class="td2">
        <button type="button" name="add" id="add-btn" class="btn btn-success">
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does the `select2()` not displaying option 1 - 6? and this is not dynamic as well

Comment: The sample code seems to be working as expected.